# selfmade tensorflow .pb file causes cv2.error

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

Hey im currently trying to run a Onject detection with an "Homemade" model, im using OpenCV 4.8.1

i only had an .pb file and tried to get an .pbxt with
`cv2.dnn.writeTextGraph('saved_model.pb', 'saved_model.pbtxt')`.

i got folling Error-Message:
  `File "C:\[..]convert.py", line 3, in <module> cv2.dnn.writeTextGraph('saved_model.pb', 'saved_model.pbtxt') cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_io.cpp:42: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: saved_model.pb in function 'cv::dnn::ReadTFNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie'`

i tried is with another, selfmade model, but it didn`t work either...

I've read, that it might be a corrupted file but i dont know how to check that.